# Cannot update game scene instance variable when transitioning back from game over scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have something that looks like this. Where "grid" is a seperate sksprite node that draws out a texture, other sprites are initialized and finally a touple list is initialized.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {


var gameOver: Bool = false
let  grid = Grid(blockSize: 15.0, rows:29, cols:28)
var direction: Int = IDLE
var totalSeconds:Int = 0

var balls: [(Int,Int)] = [(Int,Int)]()


let Car = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: Car_IMAGE)
var Ghouls: [SKSpriteNode] = [SKSpriteNode]()


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

...

```
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when I transition to a game over scene, triggered by an update on whether the amount of balls has reached zero (which does, in fact, get triggered) I call the game over function and set the game over flag to true as such:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if self.gameOver == false {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
        print(Balls.count)
        // update balls count if sprite touches it
        self.checkForBalls()


        // check if ghouls touched car
        self.IfGameOver()

    }


}


 func IfGameOver() {
    if self.balls.count == 0 {
            goToScene(msg:"you lose")
            balls.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.gameOver = true
    }
}



 func goToGameScene(msg: String){
    let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: size)
    gameOverScene.scaleMode = scaleMode

    let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
    view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
}
```

Everything works as expected, and I am able to transition back from the game over scene back to this game scene. All instance variables get reinitialized aside from the balls array of int tuples. I know the bool flag gets reintialized because ultimately my terminal start printing the count again, but I also know my array does NOT get reinitialized because the count that is printed to the terminal is exactly double of the original size it ended up reaching.

For instance if I initialized the array as such:

```
func intializeBalls() {
// where OArray is just series of coordinates
for o in OArray {
            balls.append(o.coordinate)
    } 
}
```

Say this function ends up obtaining a final count of 30 appended items in the ball list. The next time the game over scene is cycled the terminal will print 60 balls in the list which means the last items were never deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple fix just need to remove all on OArray (i.e. OArray.removeall) and all is well in the cosmos -- Lesson learned: don't code when your tired